# Custom rendering that leverage search result rendering

Tags: sxa

I would like to create custom rendering that leverages a search result rendering in SXA.  At the same time allowing the content editor to be able to drag and drop this new rendering in any created pages without the need to configure the search result rendering, facets, scope, etc.

Can it be done using custom development that inherits from search results?

Comment: The Search Results rendering has nothing to do with facets. The results showed by Search Results can be filtered by facets but you are not configuring/selecting facets of the Search Results rendering. 
At the moment there is no way to "save" preconfigured Search Results (by preconfigured I mean preselected scope or page size) as a dropable rendering.

Comment: this cloud help http://zhenyuan.azurewebsites.net/post/extending-sitecore-sxa-search-results